# reference to function std::get<1> in tuple header

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples

How do I get a reference to a "get"-function for a specific tuple instance?

My best try is given below but does not compile against g++4.5.1

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

typedef std::tuple<int,std::string> Tuple;
auto t=(std::string& (Tuple&))(std::get<1,Tuple>);
```

The compiler error is:

```
a.cc:5: error: invalid cast to function type ‘std::string&(Tuple&)’ 
a.cc:5: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

I would like to use the function reference as an input to some stl-algorithms. I am actually a bit surprised on how non-trivial this seems to be for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works for me. The trick is to use a function-pointer typedef and not a function reference typedef. 
I am impressed that the compiler does not need all template parameters, but can optionally work out missing ones through the overloaded function type.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

typedef std::tuple<int,std::string> Tuple;
typedef std::string& (*PFun)(Tuple&);

PFun p1=(PFun)std::get<1U>;
PFun p2=(PFun)std::get<1U,int,std::string>;
```

In one line:

```
auto p3=(std::string& (*)(Tuple&))std::get<1U>;
```

Sorry to answer my own question. A night sleep can make a big difference.

Comment: Ah, if you had been okay with re-specifying the tuples types, it is indeed much shorter. :) Most of the my code is extracting them for you.

Comment: Indeed, I did not make it clear that the tuple types are not required. 

However, the standard provides tuple_element for that. So replacing std::string with std::tuple_element<1,Tuple> in the code above would have handled this as well.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want:

```
namespace detail
{
    template <std::size_t I, typename... Types>
    decltype(&std::get<I, Types...>) get_function(std::tuple<Types...>*)
    {
        return &std::get<I, Types...>;
    }
}

template <std::size_t I, typename Tuple>
decltype(detail::get_function<I>((Tuple*)nullptr)) get_function()
{
    return detail::get_function<I>((Tuple*)nullptr);
}

auto t = get_function<I, Tuple>();
```

Kind of ugly. Surely there's a better way, but that's all I have for now.

Comment: I was hoping for a one-liner, but I see how this is supposed to work. gcc-4.5.1 complains about the nullptr, and about type-deduction after that. I will try to adapt this for my compiler later.

Comment: @user Move it into a header, `#include "get_function.hpp"` is one line. :) What are the errors?

Comment: I used "#define nullptr NULL;" as a workaround and got in

decltype(detail::get_function<I>((Tuple*)nullptr)) get_function()

q.cc:19: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token
q.cc:19: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token

Comment: @user: Why do you need to define `nullptr`? It should be defined already. Keep in mind my code is untested, I just wrote it from brain; the error could be in my part and not yours.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of experimenting, I've found that it is possible using lambda expressions:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

typedef std::tuple<int, std::string> Tuple;
auto t = [] (Tuple& t) { return std::get<1> (t); };
```

If you need to use this a lot you could always write a macro:

```
#define REFERENCE_GET(N, Tuple) \
    [] (Tuple &t) { return std::get<N> (t); }
```

Comment: I did not consider myself "ready" for lambda's yet, but it looks like there is no way around them in C++0x. The only drawback seems to be that the lambda is not usable as an input to the boost::transform_iterator due to a missing result_type, but that is a different story. Thank you.